# How Grand central Dispatch is different from threading?? Confusion

Tags: objective-c, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

It is stated in GCD description that its different from traditional threading but how?
Where i understand GCD also uses threads in background. isn't it? 
Can anyone explain whats going on its background?

Thanks

Comment: GCD is effectively a system-level [thread pool and event-dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html) for executing tasks and dealing with asynchronous IO. It doesn't replace threads, but rather reduces much of the necessity of manually dealing with threads and exposes a task-based interface.

Comment: See the [WWDC 2010 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) and the [WWDC 2011 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) that bear "Grand Central Dispatch" in their title, and they touch upon the relationship between threads and GCD. Bottom line, GCD employs threads behind the scenes, but is a much easier mechanism for doing concurrency programming. See the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/), which discusses the transition from threads to GCD (and operation queues).

Comment: Take a look at my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html#_three_ways_of_threading It demonstrates how differently (i.e. how much better) GCD lets you, the programmer, interact with threads than "traditional threading" does.

Answer (score 3):

A thread is an instruction stream. That stream may be perpetual. When you create a thread you create a resource that lasts indefinitely. Threads often transition between being active and being asleep. A scheduler decides the timing with which different threads will use different processing cores.

A GCD queue is a list of individual items of work, each of them encapsulated in a block. Each piece of work is usually finite. If it is a concurrent queue then arbitrarily many of those will be ongoing at any one time, with those still in the queue being dispatched whenever is appropriate. If it is a serial queue then only the first of those will be ongoing, with the second having to wait until the first is finished.

So the main semantic differences are:

- threads are usually perpetual; blocks are usually finite; and
- a thread is always serial; a queue is potentially concurrent.

The main delimiter between usage of the two is whether you want an ongoing actor or just want to perform individual actions.

GCD uses threads as part of its implementation but similarly variables tend to utilise registers; the two are definitely not the same thing and the higher-level one doesn't just wrap the lower.

Comment: I really like your answer, but its not very beginner friendly to read ;-)

Comment: There is nothing to stop a block being "perpetual", and one point of threads (note the plural) is "potential concurrency".

Comment: Despite the edit I still think you're drawing a wrong distinction here. Its more block vs. thread and queue vs. threads rather than what you have which is thread vs. queue. E.g. a single thread/block is serial, a queue/threads are potentially concurrent

Answer (score 0):

GCD is an abstraction built over threads with the aim of making certain uses of concurrency or asynchrony easier. GCD is not a replacement for all uses of threads. Apple does provide [Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html) to show how some thread-based models can be replaced by GCD-based ones.

Code running on a thread usually has full control of that thread; it can suspend it, terminate it, block on a semaphore, etc. The code is often large and threads are expected to have long lifetimes; however neither of these are requirements and small short-lived threads are used.

A block scheduled by GCD is typically short, but again need not be. While the block is executed on a thread the block should not attempt to directly control the thread, so no suspending it etc. GCD does however provide its own semaphores that can be used.

GCD provides multiple queues on which blocks may be placed to be executed, and each queue can be either sequential - where only one block from the queue is executed at a time - or concurrent - where multiple blocks may be removed from the queue and executed concurrently. There are facilities to schedule blocks after a group of other blocks have completed. One standard queue is the main sequential one and blocks executing from this queue may do UI work.

These features all combine to provide a system where blocks need to do little direct synchronisation, locking, etc. themselves - GCD handles all this. For example a concurrent block can be scheduled to perform some long running task. When that task is complete the block itself can schedule another block on the sequential main queue to perform any UI updates needed. Of course the block can do this without terminating, or schedule another concurrent block, if there is more work to do.

Overall the GCD model is to break your task into a collection of small chunks (non-technical term to avoid using "block"), each of which is sequential but different chunks may execute concurrently, with chunks passing results to future chunks they schedule. There is some similarity here to *continuation passing style*.

HTH